# Is there any python library or API for Deep Learning?

Tags: python, machine-learning, tensorflow, deep-learning

I need to do some deep learning work in python, mainly image processing based work. Do Python have any standard library or API for Deep Learning?

Comment: The same question was asked on http://datascience.stackexchange.com/q/694/843 : there are plenty of pointers there.

Answer (score 2):

Most deep-learning libraries primarily serve the Python community. These include Theano, TensorFlow and Caffe, as well as libraries working atop Theano and TF, such as Keras. Caffe is a popular library for imaging processing with a Python API.